# Swiper on page load showing a slide full width, then a 1-2 second delay for JavaScript to apply and split it into 8 columns?

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper to create a slider divided into 6 columns. The issue is that when the page loads, the browser displays only one slide taking up the full screen width. After about 1-2 seconds, the JavaScript applies and divides the Swiper into 6 columns. How can I solve this problem?

Html code:

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
                <img class="w-100 object-fit-cover" src="/images/logo1.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
                <img class="w-100 object-fit-cover" src="/images/logo2.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
                <img class="w-100 object-fit-cover" src="/images/logo3.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
                <img class="w-100 object-fit-cover" src="/images/logo4.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
                <img class="w-100 object-fit-cover" src="/images/logo5.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="ratio ratio-1x1">
                <img class="w-100 object-fit-cover" src="/images/logo6.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var swiperBrand = new Swiper(".brand .swiper", {
    spaceBetween: 24,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        480: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        640: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        1200: {
            slidesPerView: 6,
        }
    }
});
```

I implemented a flexbox that is initially displayed on page load and hides the swiper. Once the swiper is loaded, the flexbox is hidden and the swiper is shown. However, this approach results in lengthy code. I'm looking for a solution to optimize this process. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks